How to set ldapsearch timeout in GO?
Could you please clarify how to CORRECTLY set the timeout for the ldapsearch operation.
I see SearchRequest.TimeLimit . As far as I can tell, this option limits the maximum duration of ldapsearch, but it is not clear to me in what units this limitation works - seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds?

As per RFC 4511 (LDAP protocol specification) Section 4.5.1.5 searchRequest.timeLimit is in seconds. You can see in ldap/search.go:
func (req *SearchRequest) appendTo(envelope *ber.Packet) error {
    pkt := ber.Encode(ber.ClassApplication, ber.TypeConstructed, ApplicationSearchRequest, nil, "Search Request")
    ...
    pkt.AppendChild(ber.NewInteger(ber.ClassUniversal, ber.TypePrimitive, ber.TagInteger, uint64(req.TimeLimit), "Time Limit"))
    ...
}

this attribute is directly appended to BER encoded LDAP packet.
NOTE: Although it may seem obvious to package authors, I agree this should be documented (if not per-field at least point to RFC and say there's no transformation done to these fields).
